# Tensorflow; applying spectral normalization via kernel_constraint to layers.dense()

Tags: tensorflow

I'm about to implement the following weight normalization and incorporate it into `layers.dense()` via `kernel_constraint`

[image]

The code will create a variable for each layers (from isotropic distribution) and this variable gets update for each iterations of training.

The code for a single layer update is

```
def spectral_norm(w, iteration=1):
   w_shape = w.shape.as_list()
   w = tf.reshape(w, [-1, w_shape[-1]])

   u = tf.get_variable("u", [1, w_shape[-1]], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(), trainable=False)

   u_hat = u
   v_hat = None
   for i in range(iteration):
       """
       power iteration
       Usually iteration = 1 will be enough
       """
       v_ = tf.matmul(u_hat, tf.transpose(w))
       v_hat = tf.nn.l2_normalize(v_)

       u_ = tf.matmul(v_hat, w)
       u_hat = tf.nn.l2_normalize(u_)

   u_hat = tf.stop_gradient(u_hat)
   v_hat = tf.stop_gradient(v_hat)

   sigma = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(v_hat, w), tf.transpose(u_hat))

   with tf.control_dependencies([u.assign(u_hat)]):
       w_norm = w / sigma
       w_norm = tf.reshape(w_norm, w_shape)


   return w_norm
```

However, when build neural network

```
  for units in hidden_layers:
    x = layers.dense(
        inputs=x,
        units=units,
        activation=activation,
        kernel_constraint=spectral_norm,
        *args,
        **kwargs)
```

This results in many problems; such as variable already been created.

Wondering if there any correct way of combine this two together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem using TF 1.13.

I'm currently learning to work with spectral normalization, also, I'm not sure if this is the proper answer, but I think the problem is that you are trying to reuse the "u" variable which may have a different shape at every layer.

I added a name input to the "spectral_norm" function:

```
def spectral_norm(w, iteration=1, nombre='u'):
    w_shape = w.shape.as_list()
    w = tf.reshape(w, [-1, w_shape[-1]])

    with tf.variable_scope(nombre, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        u = tf.get_variable(nombre, [1, w_shape[-1]], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(), trainable=False)

    u_hat = u
    v_hat = None
    for i in range(iteration):

       """
        power iteration
        Usually iteration = 1 will be enough
        """

        v_ = tf.matmul(u_hat, tf.transpose(w))
        v_hat = tf.nn.l2_normalize(v_)

        u_ = tf.matmul(v_hat, w)
        u_hat = tf.nn.l2_normalize(u_)

    u_hat = tf.stop_gradient(u_hat)
    v_hat = tf.stop_gradient(v_hat)

    sigma = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(v_hat, w), tf.transpose(u_hat))

    with tf.control_dependencies([u.assign(u_hat)]):
        w_norm = w / sigma
        w_norm = tf.reshape(w_norm, w_shape)


    return w_norm
```

and then declared the kernel constrain as a lambda function with different variable names:

```
for idx_layer, units in enumerate(hidden_layers):
    kern_const = lambda x: spectral_norm(x, iteration=1, nombre = 'layer_%d'%idx_layer+'_u')
    x = layers.dense(inputs=x,
        units=units,
        activation=activation,
        kernel_constraint=kern_const,
        *args,
        **kwargs)
```

This code seems to be working, but it does not feel natural...